# Using jquery 2.2.2 in a grails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, grails

I'm trying to change javascript library versions in a grails project to use compatible versions. We've added Angularjs 1.5.2 to the project. That requires jquery 2.1+ (https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq). We're currently using jquery 1.10.2, but 2.2.2 is the latest. The grails way to update this is to edit BuildConfig.groovy and run grails refresh-dependencies. HOWEVER, the grails jquery plugin only supports jquery up through 1.11.1. (https://grails.org/plugin/jquery) Is there a proper grails way to address this?

I'm using grails 2.2.5.

Comment: why not disable the grails plugin and drop in the required versions then call them in ApplicationResources.groovy. Here is an example this is digging back in time https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testingarrested/blob/b3a61605eecbfe5982f8439d129b1cf3f55a73c4/grails-app/conf/ApplicationResources.groovy

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I applied @vahid's suggestion. First step was to download jquery and jquery-ui, and put the necessary files in place. For us, that was:

```
js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js
css/blitzer/jquery-ui.custom.css
```

Then, removed the grails-jquery plugin references from BuildConfig.groovy:

```
runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
```

And added the jquery and jquery-ui modules to Config.groovy:

```
jquery {
    resource url: 'js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
}

'jquery-ui' {
    resource url: 'js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js'
    resource url: 'css/blitzer/jquery-ui.custom.css'
}
```

The ticks around jquery-ui are essential. I removed our jquery-theme override as well.

The final step was to adjust the versions as needed.